# Convert DLL to .dylib or .so

Tags: android, ios, dll, xamarin, dylib

I have a Xamarin project with some dll libraries, I would like to go native iOS (swift) and Android (java). Is it possible to convert my dll libraries to .dylib and .so through Xamarin in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is not possible. It is only possible to bind Objective-C and Java libraries to make them accessible in C#, but not the other way around.